# Laravel Passport calls for oauth_access_tokens every time I get User from request or Auth facade

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have strange Passport behavior:
I have non protected (public) endpoint in my API
for example: `GET: mysite.com/posts` (no auth middleware here).
This endpoint can be called with Authorization header (with bearer token).
While I am handling request I check few times if there is loggedIn User with code:
`Auth::user()` or `$request->user()`
Every call produce SQL querie: `select * from oauth_access_tokens where id = fwefwe435 limit 1`
So I have 100500 duplicated queries and this is a problem.
Can I somehow reduce this amount?

I've tried to use `$request->setUserResolver()` but no affect.

Ugly hack - just to cache queries from `Laravel\Passport\TokenRepository`

Comment: I don't currently have a solution, but it looks like you're affected by this: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/382